# Cant find Google Base tab under Google API

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I was searching about How to create froogle.xml file in magento and i came to know that it can be done through Google Base which can be founded under Google Api tab . But in my case there is no Google Base tab there .  I am using version 1.7 .
Is there some configuration error or some other issues ?

Answer (score 1):

Google has retired its old Google Base Data API and replaced it with its new Google Content API for Shopping. Check this [Google Content API for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-content-api-for-shopping.html)